# Is there a reason to use "[ ! -f file ] || command" instead of "[ -f file ] && command"?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I found

```
[ ! -f /etc/default/lxc-net ] || . /etc/default/lxc-net
```

in `/etc/default/lxc` on Ubuntu 16.04 which seems to be replacing (my own or package maintainer code)

```
[ -f /etc/default/lxc-net ] && . /etc/default/lxc-net
```

Since the test is counter-intuitive (in case of failure of the test about non-presence of the file run the command) I was wondering if it has any advantage over the `&&`-version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if you care about the [exit code of the compound statement](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html#EXITSTATUSREF). Try the following:

```
#! /bin/sh -

! "$@" || true
echo "$?"

"$@" && true
echo "$?"
```

then run it with `true` and `false` as arguments.

```
./script true
0
0

./script false
0
1
```

This is because [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of boolean expressions.

In OP's example, let's suppose *the file doesn't exist*:

- In the first case, the first condition returns TRUE, no need to evaluate the second operation (`TRUE OR x = TRUE`). You get a TRUE for the compound statement.
- In the second case, the first condition returns FALSE, no need to evaluate the second operation (`FALSE AND x = FALSE`). You get a FALSE for the compound statement.

Exit codes are very important. Check [What does set -e mean in a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34381499/253049) to see possible implications of `set -e`, `trap` and `set -o pipefail`.

Comment: You might want to point to the `-e` option as one reason one might well care very much about exit codes.

Comment: @JdeBP: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script, the most accepted answer is to use `trap` instead of `set -e`. Besides that, there is the recommendation of also setting `set -o pipefail`.

Comment: @JdeBP though `a || b`/`a && b` seems like the one place where you wouldn't care about the exit code of `a` w.r.t `set -e`, since `set -e` will only be triggered by the final command in the chain ([the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-trap) says: "The `ERR` trap is not executed if the failed command is ... part of a command executed in a `&&` or `||` list except the command following the final `&&` or `||`... These are the same conditions obeyed by the `errexit` (`-e`) option. " )

Answer (score 0):

`[  -f file ]` is true when `file` exists **and** is a `plain file`.

`[ ! -f file ]` is true when `file` does not exist **or** is another file type.

So there is no real difference - except for readability.